# Bitmap Factory not display images

Tags: android

I use my phones camera to capture a picture, and then set it to my imageview. I was getting a out of memory error, so i decided to use the following code to compress my bitmap. The error has gone, but so is my bitmap. My imageview does not display anything. What am i doing wrong. The following code is in my onActivityResult.

```
InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                            data.getData());
                    //Decode image size
                        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,null,o);

                        //The new size we want to scale to
                        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=40;

                        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                        int scale=16;
                        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                            scale*=2;

                        //Decode with inSampleSize
                        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, o2);

                        firstImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished working on a similar routine. I found that I needed to close and then reopen my inputstream between the two calls to decodeStream as it is not repositioned to the start of the stream otherwise.

Also you do not need to use a new BitmapFactory.options for the second call to decodeStream, just set the o.inJustDecodeBounds to false and o.inSampleSize=scale and use it instead of o2.

```
InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

//Decode image size
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,null,o);
input.close();

//The new size we want to scale to
final int REQUIRED_SIZE=40;

//Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
int scale=16;
while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
    scale*=2;

//Decode with inSampleSize
input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
o.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
o.inSampleSize=scale;
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, o);

firstImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```